# Apply :hover on parent div but not on child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

What I want is to hover over my div and give it a box-shadow to show that it is clickable, I have some content and a button inside it which should not have the box shadow. The button enlarges on hover. I managed to get the box-shadow on the div and remove the box-shadow on content by using `pointer-events:none` but  am unable to remove the shadow from the button as it is clickable and cannot use `pointer-events:none`. Is there any css only solution and if not, any other solution? jsfiddle link->https://jsfiddle.net/uzq13s47/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css"/>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="box">
            <p>content</p>
            <h5><button>click me!</button></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#box {
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
p {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#container :hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgb(137, 137, 138);
}
h5 :hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `:hover` as you want to, that white space between selector and pseudo class (`#container :hover`) it means all child element will have the hover effect, in code means (`#content *:hover`), and that's why you have the `p` and the `button` with the hover effect.

You can remove that white space and apply the hover in `#box` and `button` only

Also I would advise not using the heading `h5` as parent of the `button` because it isn't much correct in terms of semantics

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

#box {
  background-color: cyan;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgb(137, 137, 138);
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box">
    <p>content</p>
    <button class="button">click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!. It worked .I did not think the space would play any role and used it for aesthetic reasons.